# What should login function in LoginRepository return?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Android Studio provides a Login Activity template. There's a lot of code, so I'll show you the Repository, DataSource and a view model:

LoginDataSource:

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.data;

import com.umk.packit.Login.data.model.LoggedInUser;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Class that handles authentication w/ login credentials and retrieves user information.
 */
public class LoginDataSource {
    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String email, String password) {
        try {
            // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
            LoggedInUser fakeUser = new LoggedInUser(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane Doe");
            return new Result.Success<>(fakeUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }
}
```

Result

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.data;

/**
 * A generic class that holds a result success w/ data or an error exception.
 */
public class Result<T> {
    // hide the private constructor to limit subclass types (Success, Error)
    private Result() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this instanceof Result.Success) {
            Result.Success success = (Result.Success) this;
            return "Success[data=" + success.getData().toString() + "]";
        } else if (this instanceof Result.Error) {
            Result.Error error = (Result.Error) this;
            return "Error[exception=" + error.getError().toString() + "]";
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Success sub-class
    public final static class Success<T> extends Result {
        private T data;

        public Success(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return this.data;
        }
    }

    // Error sub-class
    public final static class Error extends Result {
        private Exception error;

        public Error(Exception error) {
            this.error = error;
        }

        public Exception getError() {
            return this.error;
        }
    }
}
```

LoginRepository:

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.data;

import com.umk.packit.Login.data.model.LoggedInUser;

/**
 * Class that requests authentication and user information from the remote data source and
 * maintains an in-memory cache of login status and user credentials information.
 */
public class LoginRepository {
    // private constructor : singleton access
    private LoginRepository(LoginDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public static LoginRepository getInstance(LoginDataSource dataSource) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LoginRepository(dataSource);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String email, String password) {
        // handle login
        Result<LoggedInUser> result = dataSource.login(email, password);
        if (result instanceof Result.Success) {
            setLoggedInUser(((Result.Success<LoggedInUser>) result).getData());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return user != null;
    }

    public void logout() {
        user = null;
        dataSource.logout();
    }

    private void setLoggedInUser(LoggedInUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    private static volatile LoginRepository instance;

    private final LoginDataSource dataSource;

    private LoggedInUser user = null;
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.ui.login;

import android.util.Patterns;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.umk.packit.Login.data.LoginRepository;
import com.umk.packit.Login.data.Result;
import com.umk.packit.Login.data.model.LoggedInUser;
import com.umk.packit.R;

public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    LoginViewModel(LoginRepository loginRepository) {
        this.loginRepository = loginRepository;
    }

    public void login(String email, String password) {
        // can be launched in a separate asynchronous job
        Result<LoggedInUser> result = loginRepository.login(email, password);

        if (result instanceof Result.Success) {
            LoggedInUser data = ((Result.Success<LoggedInUser>) result).getData();
            loginResult.setValue(new LoginResult(new LoggedInUserView(data.getDisplayName())));
        } else {
            loginResult.setValue(new LoginResult(R.string.login_failed));
        }
    }

    public void loginDataChanged(String email, String password) {
        if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(R.string.invalid_email, null));
        } else if (!isPasswordValid(password)) {
            loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(null, R.string.invalid_password));
        } else {
            loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(true));
        }
    }

    // A placeholder email validation check
    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        if (email == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (email.contains("@")) {
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        } else {
            return !email.trim().isEmpty();
        }
    }

    // A placeholder password validation check
    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        return password != null && password.trim().length() > 5;
    }

    LiveData<LoginFormState> getLoginFormState() {
        return loginFormState;
    }

    LiveData<LoginResult> getLoginResult() {
        return loginResult;
    }

    private MutableLiveData<LoginFormState> loginFormState = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<LoginResult> loginResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;
}
```

LoggedInUserView

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.ui.login;

public class LoggedInUserView {
    LoggedInUserView(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    private final String displayName;
    //... other data fields that may be accessible to the UI
}
```

LoginResult

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.ui.login;

//Authentication result : success (user details) or error message.
class LoginResult {
    LoginResult(@Nullable Integer error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    LoginResult(@Nullable LoggedInUserView success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @Nullable
    LoggedInUserView getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    @Nullable
    Integer getError() {
        return error;
    }

    @Nullable
    private LoggedInUserView success;
    @Nullable
    private Integer error;
}
```

LoginFormState:

```java
package com.umk.packit.Login.ui.login;


class LoginFormState {
    LoginFormState(@Nullable Integer emailError, @Nullable Integer passwordError) {
        this.emailError = emailError;
        this.passwordError = passwordError;
        this.isDataValid = false;
    }

    LoginFormState(boolean isDataValid) {
        this.emailError = null;
        this.passwordError = null;
        this.isDataValid = isDataValid;
    }

    @Nullable
    Integer getEmailError() {
        return emailError;
    }

    @Nullable
    Integer getPasswordError() {
        return passwordError;
    }

    boolean isDataValid() {
        return isDataValid;
    }

    @Nullable
    private final Integer emailError;
    @Nullable
    private final Integer passwordError;
    private final boolean isDataValid;
}
```

I want to modify this code to fit firebase auth. I know that I need to get the instance of `FirebaseAuth` and there're methods like: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String, String)` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword(String, String)`.

Since I want to use firebase I believe there's no need to have 'LoginDataSource`class,`Result`class,`LoggedInUser`class,`LoginFormState`class,`LoginResult`class,`LoggedInUserView` class (arguable).

I'm not sure what's the best way to implement the login repository to work with a view model and an activity.

The way that the template is implemented looks clear to me. Since the default implementation it's single threaded and firebase uses callbacks I'm not sure what `LoginRepository.login` function should return. Should it return a `Task<AuthResult>`?

```java
public Task<AuthResult> login(String email, String password) {
        return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }
```

But now that's the point of having `LoginViewModel`? Unless it'll do some UI things, but if not, `LoginViewModel.login` would just be this:

```java
Task<AuthResult> login(String email, String password) {
   return loginRepo.login(email, password);
}
```

The reason I'd like to have some kind of result like `Task<AuthResult>` type be combatible with the activity is to be able to know if the authorization failed or successed to manage widgets.

What should I do? Return `Task<AuthResult>` from `LoginRepository.login` and get rid of `LoginViewModel`? Return `Task<AuthResult> from` LoginRepository.login`and keep the`LoginViewModel`? How should I handle it?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: Nah, the code works fine, but I'm not sure how to handle the communication between the repository, ViewModel and activity. I want to login using an email and a password and if it successes -> change activity to whatever, let's say, MainAppAcitivity, if it fails -> display something on a screen (not a toast, please). Since firebase auth works on a background thread, the `FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function returns a callback, so I cannot get results immediately like in the Login Activity that Android studio provides.

Comment: Summarising I don't know if my `LoginRepository.login` function should return `Task<AuthResult>` or something else. If `Task<AuthResult>`, should I get rid of `LoginViewModel`?

Comment: I've seen this article already.